# Save an xml file with the value of a node

Tags: c#, xml

I have a file that contains a CSV entry that I am using to create XML. Right now I am saving it with a generic name, but what I would like to do is use the value of a node or a combination of multiple nodes as the name of the xml file so it is unique.

For example,

```
C:\LOGGER 20150119\013521sa.au,Line01,20150119,013521,value,Yes,No,Out,7652816686,1,something,2220
```

and I would like the save the file as

```
C:/Line01_value.xml.
```

Would thise be possible? This is what I am using to create the xml right now:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file.csv");
        XElement xml = new XElement("root",
            from str in lines
            let columns = str.Split(',')
            select new XElement("recording_info",
                new XElement("recorded_accound_id", columns[1]),//Line01
                new XElement("date_created_ts", String.Format("{0:####-##-##  ##:##:##}", Convert.ToInt64(columns[2] + columns[3]))),     //date                               
                new XElement("recorded_cid", columns[9]),//1
                 new XElement("recording_tag", columns[1]),//Line01
                new XElement("from_caller_id", columns[10] + "  <"+columns[8]+ ">")//ball memorial H



                ) );
        xml.Save(@"C:\XMLFile.xml");<<I want to change this..
```

EDIT: What all of this is for is I have a CSV with multiple csv entries and I need to create an XML for each entry and save it using values from the xml/csv so it would be unique

Comment: Line01 is a variable I assume?

Comment: Yes the first formatted code is the csv file with the values I use..I'm creating an xml  from csv, so Line01 would be node[1] and value would be node[4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for each line in your file, use new object of anonymous type to get your filename and an XElement to save (I removed 'root' node here), then save the files:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file.csv");

var xmls = (from str in lines
                let columns = str.Split(',')
                select new
                {
                     XFILENAME = columns[1] + "_" + columns[4],
                     XELEM = new XElement("recording_info",
                         new XElement("recorded_accound_id", columns[1]),//Line01
                         new XElement("date_created_ts", String.Format("{0:####-##-##  ##:##:##}", Convert.ToInt64(columns[2] + columns[3]))),     //date                               
                         new XElement("recorded_cid", columns[9]),//1
                         new XElement("recording_tag", columns[1]),//Line01
                         new XElement("from_caller_id", columns[10] + "  <" + columns[8] + ">"))
                }).ToList();

            xmls.ForEach(a => a.XELEM.Save(@"C:\" + a.XFILENAME + ".xml"));
```

or use a dictionary:

```
var xmls2 = (from str in lines
                         let columns = str.Split(',')
                         select new KeyValuePair<string, XElement>(
                             columns[1] + "_" + columns[4],
                             new XElement("recording_info",
                                 new XElement("recorded_accound_id", columns[1]),//Line01
                                 new XElement("date_created_ts", String.Format("{0:####-##-##  ##:##:##}", Convert.ToInt64(columns[2] + columns[3]))),     //date                               
                                 new XElement("recorded_cid", columns[9]),//1
                                 new XElement("recording_tag", columns[1]),//Line01
                                 new XElement("from_caller_id", columns[10] + "  <" + columns[8] + ">"))
                         )).ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);

foreach (var o in xmls2)
{
     o.Value.Save(@"C:\" + o.Key + ".xml");
}
```